# Why was this conversation muted first and revealed later?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-2017

In *Wonder Woman (2017)*, this conversation is shown with no audio. But the same scene appeared later, with sound, when Diana and Ares battle each other.

> Diana: What?
>
> Steve: I have to go.
>
> Diana: What are you saying? Steve, whatever it is, I can do it.
>
> Steve: No. No.
>
> Diana: Let me do it.
>
> Steve: No.It has to be me. It has to be me. I can save today. You could
>   save the world. I wish we had more time.
>
> Diana: What? What are you saying?
>
> Steve: I love you! (leaving his watch in Diana's hand)

Comment: It was muted because we're meant to feel like the characters, deaf from the explosion, I guess it was later revealed because it is important to her character development

Comment: Yeah, in-universe, it's because Diana was temporarily deaf and couldn't hear him, but later remembered as her head cleared up. Out-of-universe, it's so they could have this big "I Love You" reveal, giving WW the power of love and enabling her super duper end-of-movie protagonist powers.

Comment: :) Does one of you want to turn their comment into an answer?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots probably not because neither of us broke 300 characters

Comment: @Edlothiad: I hope you don't mind that I wrote up an answer with both of your comments. It seemed important to have an answer. :)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Go ahead. When I leave comments that are answers I expect someone to steal it. Think of it as, me wanting to get the rep, but being too lazy, so someone else can have the rep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the caveat that I have not yet seen the film, as indicated by Edlothiad and DisturbedNeo, the use of silence served two purposes, both to help us share the protagonist perspective and to set up a later reveal for the audience.

**In-character perspective**
Both protagonists have been deafened from the explosion. For this reason, we get a muted scene to reflect the perspective of the characters, isolated by their lack of ability to hear. Wonder Woman, due to her Amazon prowess, heard more of what was being said than she realized, but it took a while for her to recover from the explosion rattling her.

**Out of character plotting**
The second reason is that it sets up the revelation that Steve declared his love to Wonder Woman during the scene. If introduced earlier in the film, this revelation would have flavored the viewer's interpretation of the following scenes, and would have cheapened her realization of his declaration, which gave her a heroic second wind. One could even argue that, without this coming at just the right moment, she might have arrived at the final battle having already used up that inspiration and lacking the final push that allowed her victory.